# Swift Json data parsing without array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have working json data parsing `array` codes but I want to change it to `Dictionary` parsing. My new json file

```
{
  "Id": 450,
  "Name": "NameforItem",
  "Image": "234234.jpg"
}
```

My old json file working success

```
[{
  "Id": 450,
  "Name": "NameforItem",
  "Image": "234234.jpg"
}]
```

My parsing codes.

```
 /// Convert JSON data into  array
    private func getFromJSON(jsonData: NSData) throws -> [Place] {
        var places = [Place]()
        do {
            if let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for i in jsonArray {
                    var properties = [String: AnyObject]()
                    properties[placeJSONKeys.Id] = i[placeJSONKeys.Id]
                    properties[placeJSONKeys.Name] = i[placeJSONKeys.Name]
                    let place = Place(properties: properties)
                    places.append(place)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            throw TMDBErrors.ParsingError
        }
        return places
    }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to change return type of your function to `Optional`:

```
private func getFromJSON(jsonData: NSData) throws -> Place? {
    var place: Place?
    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
            var properties = [String: AnyObject]()
            properties[placeJSONKeys.Id] = json[placeJSONKeys.Id]
            properties[placeJSONKeys.Name] = json[placeJSONKeys.Name]
            place = Place(properties: properties)
        }
    } catch {
        throw TMDBErrors.ParsingError
    }
    return place
}
```

**updated**

```
 private func getFromJSON(jsonData: NSData) throws -> Place? {
    var place: Place?
    do {
        if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {


            place = Place(properties: json)
        }
    } catch {
        throw TMDBErrors.ParsingError
    }
    return place
}
```

Comment: @Shadow Of Worked Ty I will approve it soon

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper - one question , check one the updated answer also

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper - the reason `placeJSONKeys` is the struct class , you can directly access the objcet in anywhere

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yeah i understand Thank you !

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper-- happy to hear , have a nice day my buddy , do well .. bye

Answer (score 1):

Change your `[[String: AnyObject]]` with `[String: AnyObject]` because now it is dictionary not array

```
do {
    if let jsonDic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: .AllowFragments) as? [String: AnyObject] {
        print(jsonDic["Id"])
        print(jsonDic["Name"])
        print(jsonDic["Image"])
    }
} catch {
    throw TMDBErrors.ParsingError
}
```

Comment: why you are increase the memory you can directly access the JSonarray dictionary no need of loop in here bro